# How to print all permutations of a string

Tags: python

Writing a program to print all permutations of a string

```py
def permute(s, answer):
    if (len(s) == 0):
        print(answer, end="  ")
        return
 
    for i in range(len(s)):
        left_substr = s[0:i]
        right_substr = s[i + 1:]
        rest = left_substr + right_substr
        permute(rest, answer + ch)
 
answer = ""
 
s = "ABC"
 
print("All possible strings are : ")
permute(s, answer)
```

I was expecting to get the permutations of string.

Comment: What is your expected outputs?  -Did you check the *permutations* in standard lib?

Comment: `permute(rest, answer + ch)` what is `ch`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

Note - your program won't run, because the syntax error pointed out earlier. And this will **Not** use the *permutations* lib method.  (assuming this is some kind of *assignment)* ;-)

```py
def permute(s):
    if len(s) == 1:
        return [s]
    
    outs = []
    
    for i, ch in enumerate(s):
        outs += [ch + p for p in permute(s[:i] + s[i+1:])]
    return outs


print(permute('ABC'))
# ['ABC', 'ACB', 'BAC', 'BCA', 'CAB', 'CBA']
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is not clear. This is also one of the ways:

```
from itertools import permutations as p
s="ABC"
for x in range(len(s)+1):
    print(list(p(s,x)))

[()]
[('A',), ('B',), ('C',)]
[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'A'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'A'), ('C', 'B')]
[('A', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'C', 'B'), ('B', 'A', 'C'), ('B', 'C', 'A'), ('C', 'A', 'B'), ('C', 'B', 'A')]
```

Link to doc: [itertools.permutations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)

If you are looking for this:

```
[''.join(y) for y in p(s,3)]
['ABC', 'ACB', 'BAC', 'BCA', 'CAB', 'CBA']
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have wrote:

```
left_substr = s[0:i]
right_substr = s[i + 1:]
rest = left_substr + right_substr
permute(rest, answer + left_substr)
```

for permutations of string, `left_substr` should be `s[i]` and the `rest` should be `s[0:i] + right_subst`. It is important to mention that `s[0:i]` is different from `s[i]`.The first one refers to a slice of the list from index 0 to index i, while `s[i]` refers to the element at index i.
So, your final code should be:

```
def permute(s, answer):
    if (len(s) == 0):
        print(answer, end="  ")
        return

    for i in range(len(s)):
        left_substr = s[i]
        right_substr = s[i + 1:]
        rest = s[0:i] + right_substr
        permute(rest, answer + left_substr)


answer = ""
s = "ABC"
print("All possible strings are : ")
permute(s, answer)
```